# Change RDP shortcut icon in Windows 10

Tags: remote-desktop, icons

I have several RDP shortcuts on my windows 10 desktop which I would like to have different icons for each of them. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Move your RDP files into a folder. Now copy and paste shortcuts to the desktop for each file. Now you can change the icons to whatever you prefer.

Comment: There is also a tutorial here on how to get rid of the shortcut arrows if you do not like them. http://www.windowscentral.com/how-get-rid-shortcut-arrows-windows-10